# C# Visit multiple links with Webbrowser

Tags: c#, asynchronous, autoresetevent

I have multiple links that I want to visit in a loop.

After visiting a site I want the thread to wait until `documentCompleted` is completed before I visit the next link.

```
foreach (HtmlElement link in linkArray)
{
    OpenNewProduct(link.ToString());
}

public void OpenNewProduct(string url)
{
    WebBrowser webBrowser = new WebBrowser(); 
    webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += product_DocumentCompleted;
    webBrowser.Navigated += new WebBrowserNavigatedEventHandler(webBrowser1_Navigated);
    webBrowser.Navigate(url);

    _waitForPageProccesingHandle.WaitOne();
}

private void product_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    notHeb();
    notRedirected(sender, e);

    ((Control)webBrowser1).Enabled = false;
    getProduct();
    _waitForPageProccesingHandle.Set();
}
```

The browser is freezing on `WaitOne()`.

For some reason async methods or autoresetevent don't seem to work.

I need to find a way to wait until `documentCompleted` is completed.

Answer (score 0):

The browser is using usually one GUI thread. You at blocking the thread with WaitOne. You should use a different synchronization mechanism which works in one thread.

Comment: Hmm, you should never  block the GUI thread.For your problem you can just schedule a new task on the gui thread when the document was completed. This could be done by using a timer and setting the OpenNewProduct as the timer function.